# PHP PostgreSQL array to string

Tags: php, sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a problem in my PHP script that uses PostgreSQL for fetching and storing data.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
 $q = "SELECT id FROM playlisty WHERE id_profilu=1;";
 $r = pg_query($q);
 $arr = pg_fetch_all($r);
 echo '<pre>'; var_dump($arr); echo'</pre>';
```

The output generated by the above code snippet:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1549"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1965"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "2047"
  }
}
```

However, I would prefer if the output looked something like the following: `2014, 1549, 1965, 2047` (i.e. a simple array of `id`-s of certain playlists).
I also tried using implode (to no anvil), and got `Array,Array,Array,Array` as a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just loop it ?

```
$str=""; 
foreach($yourarr as $arr) 
{ 
    $str.=implode(',',$arr).',';
} 
echo rtrim($str,','); //"prints" 2014, 1549, 1965, 2047
```

Comment: When i loop it can i use it in "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN ($str)" ?

Comment: I don't have an idea what results that query would return...By the way did you try the code which I gave you ?

Comment: Yes, for me the result is "2014154919652047" - as You can see there is no commas

Comment: $q = "SELECT id FROM playlisty WHERE id_profilu=1 ";
$r = pg_query($q);
$yourarr = pg_fetch_all($r);
$str="";
foreach($yourarr as $arr)
{
$str.=implode(',',$arr);
}
echo $str;

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before `echo`:

```
$arr = array_map(function ($v) { return $v['id']; }, $arr);
```

If you want to output result as string then you have to use implode [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). Replace last line with this:

```
echo '<pre>'. implode(', ', $arr). '</pre>';
```

Comment: it returned "array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "2014"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1549"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "1965"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "2047"
}"

Comment: If you want to output result as string you have to use `implode` function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) instead of `var_dump`: echo `'<pre>'; implode(', ', $arr); echo'</pre>';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array(
            0=>array('id'=>"2014"),
            1=>array('id'=>"2015"),
            2=>array('id'=>"2016"),
        );
        $ids = array_map(function($item) { return $item['id']; }, $array);
        $result = implode($ids,',');
        var_dump($result);
```

Output: string '2014,2015,2016' (length=14)

Answer (score 0):

Do select like this:

```
$q = "SELECT array_to_string(id, ',') AS id FROM playlisty WHERE id_profilu=1 ";
```

Comment: and how do i get the result from this ?

Comment: Like this: `$arr[0]['id']` will return `2014,2015,2016[,...]`. You don't have need to implode using php.